# cmake 3.9 target_link_libraries to static imported library failed. Same CMakefile works with CMake 2.8.12

Tags: static, cmake, linker, shared

I have the following CMakefile works well with CMake 2.8.12 but failed after upgrade to 3.9:

```
add_library(extlib STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property( TARGET extlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR}/extlib.a )
add_executable( myApp myApp.cpp )
target_link_libraries( myApp extlib)
```

cmake generates Makefile. But make failed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../ext/lib/extlib.a(extlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I run make VERBOSE=1 showing the following:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/myApp.dir/myApp.cpp.o  -o myApp -Wl,-rpath,/root/myApp/ext/lib ../../ext/lib/extlib.a
```

extlib.a is linked as a shared library.

The CMakefile has no problem with 2.8.12.

What do I need to modify to make it work in 3.9?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message means that you build executable with `-fPIC`, but library is built without it. Whether library is static or shared is unrelated. Either recompile your library with `-fPIC`, or compile your executable without it by adding `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)` before your commands.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, I tried you suggestion, but it is still not working. I compare the c++ options generated by 2.8 and 3.9, that are actually the same. Both don't have -fPIC flag. There is another difference is that I upgraded from gcc 4.8.5 to 7.2. Maybe that is the reason. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, changing compiler version could be very well a reason. As compilation lines are the same both for CMake 3.9 and 2.8 versions,  CMake seems out of game. If you have both CMake 2.8 and 3.9 installed, why do not try CMake 2.8 with newest compiler?

Comment: Resolved. The problem seems that without fPIC option, gcc 7.2 still expect fPIC built library but gcc 4.8.5 doesn't. I recompiled the extlib with fPIC option and it is working now. Thank you very much!